# What is Sam's probability of success at the Olympics?

Tags: probability

Sam is in a team of probables for Olympics. There are $m$ members in that team. But only $n$ would get a ticket to Olympics. Each member is equally talented and hence everyone has equal chance of making it to the Olympics.

There are $x$ members from Sam's state, including him, in the team of probables. Sam believes that he would perform well at the Olympics only if at least $y$ members from his state are also there with him. Calculate the probability of Sam performing well at the Olympics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sketch): Let us denote the event that Sam is picked by $S$ and the event that he will do well by $W$. Then we want $P(S\cap W)$. This is equal to $P(W\mid S)\cdot P(S)$ so we have that:

$P(S)=\binom{m-1}{n-1}/\binom{m}{n}$ because the number of arragnments that place them on the team is $\binom{m-1}{n-1}$ (to see this, just pick him first, and then there are $m-1$ people remaining and only $n-1$ more places for the olympics).

I might be missing something but I think $P(W\mid S)$ is not as straight forward to calculate. You want the probability that exactly $y$ of his friends go, plus the probability that exactly $y+1$ of his friends go, ...., plus the probability that exactly $x-1$ of his friends go.

This would yield:

$P(W\mid S)=\sum_{i=y}^{x-1}P(\text{exactly } i \text{ of his friends go}\mid S)$

An arbitrary term will be of the form: $\binom{x-1}{i}\binom{m-x}{n-(i+1)}/\binom{m}{n}$

I have not tried to see if one can make this solution a bit nicer.

Comment: shouldn't the upper limit of summation be x-1 instead of n-1? As i (the number of his state mates going) could be maximum of x-1, As he has x-1 other state mates in the team of probables.

Comment: @alpha_century you are right

Comment: @ Daniel Montealegre Thanks, for the answer :)